# Need to create a restricted network with UDP ports blocked in mac

Tags: macos, networking, udp, webrtc

I build video conferencing solutions using WebRTC. Some of the clients come from a restricted network with UDP ports blocked and the conferencing does not work well as the media server relies on UDP port 10000. I need to simulate the same network conditions in my mac so that without troubling the clients I can test out the video conference. 
So how to block UDP connections to my Mac? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Yasith

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pfctl` in OSX.

```sh
sudo nano /etc/pf.conf
```

At the end of the file add the following to block UDP on port 10000

```sh
block out proto udp from any to any port 10000
```

Then enable the firewall with

```sh
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf && sudo pfctl -E
```

Comment: To unblock - `pass in proto udp from any to any port 10000` 
And then run `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`

Comment: Reference - https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mac-osx-open-port/